# A specific Boost regex works fine, but if I use it inside a Boost unit test it crashes

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, boost, boost-regex

Everything worked fine with my project when using Boost 1.58 and GCC4.9, after deciding to upgrade it to Boost 1.72 and GCC9 I have started to have this problem.

I've been looking into this for a while and at first I thought it was a problem with the code of my project but I have tested it outside with the following example and it still happens.

Basically, I have this code in a main:

```
std::string s = "45.125º";

const char* pattern = 
    "^\\s*(\\+|\\-)?\\s*"
    "(?:(?:\\s*((?:[0-9]|\\.)+)(?:º|d|\\s+)))?"
    "(?:(?:\\s*((?:[0-9]|\\.)+)(?:'|m|\\s+)))?"
    "(?:(?:\\s*((?:[0-9]|\\.)+)(?:\"|s|\\s+)))?"
    "\\s*$";

const boost::regex pieces_regex(pattern);
boost::cmatch pieces_match;
if(boost::regex_match(s.c_str(), pieces_match, pieces_regex, boost::match_default)) {
    std::cout << "Match" << std::endl;
    for (auto piece : pieces_match) {
       std::cout << "Piece: " << piece.str() << std::endl;
    }
}
else std::cout << "NOPE" << std::endl;
std::cout << "DONE" << std::endl;
```

If I include boost/regex.hpp and compile it with:

```
c++ regexTest.cpp -I $BOOST_ROOT/include/ $BOOST_ROOT/lib/libboost_regex-x64.so
```

Everything works fine, if I use a string that matches it matches and if I don't it doesn't, okay.

This is the result of the execution:

```
Match
Piece: 45.125º
Piece: 
Piece: 45.125
Piece: 
Piece:
DONE
```

However, if I put this inside a Boost test:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE (test_reg)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE (test_example)
{
exactly the same code as before
}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END ()
```

And now include boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp and compile it with:

```
c++ regexTest.cpp -I $BOOST_ROOT/include/ $BOOST_ROOT/lib/libboost_regex-x64.so $BOOST_ROOT/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-x64.so
```

It still works and the test is run, but this happens:

```
Running 1 test case...
Match
Piece: 45.125º
Piece: 
Piece: 45.125
Piece: 
Piece: 
DONE

*** No errors detected
corrupted size vs. prev_size in fastbins
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I use a more simple reg expression, such as:

```
 const boost::regex pieces_regex("^[0-9]+$");
```

for example, nothing crashes despite being inside the test.

At first I thought it was a problem with my regex but it seems to work fine by itself (outside of a test) and have also tested it at https://regex101.com/.

I honestly have no idea of what else to try, I was starting to think maybe there was some kind of linkage error because I specified something wrong for CMake but the error still happens with this isolated example. Any idea of what could be going on here?

Note: The error happens in the same way inside my project (it executes fine and after saying "no errors" it crashes) but the message there is this one:

```
malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I have tried this with Boost 1.68, I get the same error.

Comment: The exact same code with Boost 1.58 and GCC9 works perfectly fine

Comment: Are you including a boost .ipp file?  I had the same problem because I was trying to cheat and use some private implementation stuff in an .ipp file.  The problem went away when didn't include that file.